# jquery can't select a simple li

Tags: jquery

could someone explain to me why in a page with this code

```
<ul id="test">
<li>bla</li>
</ul>
```

if do

```
alert($("#test").html());
```

I get the right content but if I do one the followings

```
alert($("#test li").html()); 
alert($("#test > li").html());
alert($("#test li:first-child").html());
```

I get an error in firebug saying

> $("#test li").html is not a function

EDIT: jquery is included in fact this thing doesn't make sense, could it be because this code is launched in a function in an ajax "success"?

REST OF THE CODE //right now it doesn't do anything but if I can't select the li i can't continue

```
$("#add_entry_form").submit(

                        function(){

                            //get data
                            var title = $(this).find("#title").val();
                            var body = $("#editor").val();
                            var type = $(this).find("#type").val();


                            $.ajax({
                                  type: 'POST',
                                  url: "add_entry.php",
                                  dataType: "json",
                                  data: "title="+encodeURIComponent(title)+"&body="+encodeURIComponent(body)+"&type="+type,
                                  success: function(response){                                     


                                           alert($("#test li").html());



                                  }
                            });


                        return false;

                        }
        )
```

Comment: You definitely got jQuery on that page?

Comment: all three of them are working http://jsfiddle.net/G9Yeu/

Comment: @alex How would the first one work without jQuery?

Comment: I can't get this to fail, even with multiple different elements with `id="test"`. There has to be more to this than shown

Comment: You are missing a `$` before your submit call.

Comment: Does the alert still fail if it's the first statement in the function you're passing to submit?

Comment: @Sandro Are you saying the `$("#test").html()` *does work* in the success callback?

Comment: @Phil Brown  yes correct, strange uh?

Comment: @Sandro So when you use `success:function(response){alert($('#test').html());}` You get `<li>bla</li>`?

Comment: Do any other jQuery functions work? For example `$('#test li').text()`.

Comment: Nevermind guys, it was the Firequery extension doing it! How can someone develop an extension to debug that gives you bugs!

Comment: Ouch...Next time you run into this kind of issue, fire up Chrome and test it there.

Comment: @Bryan yes that's how I found out. Thank you

Comment: haha, good call. You had a lot of people VERY confused.